# Pull data based on related table

Tags: laravel

**I have a tables:**

events[id, 'name', 'date'],

tickets ['id', event_id', 'isAvailable'],

order_tickets ['order_id', 'ticket_id'],

orders['id', 'buyer_id', 'status'].

I need to receive all orders with tickets on the events, where date >= today (do not include tickets to past events.).

**My query is next:**

```
$userId = 1;
$orders = Order::with([
        'tickets',
        'tickets.event',
    ])->where('buyer_id', $userId)
        ->where('status', 'sold')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method and the [today()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-today) helper function to achieve this:

```
$orders = Order::with('tickets.event')
    ->whereHas('tickets.event', function ($query) {
        $query->whereDate('date', '>=', today());
    })
    ->where('buyer_id', $userId)
    ->where('status', 'sold')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's help me.

Comment: @VladimirIshchenko Glad I could help!